# Truncate vim undo files

Tags: vim

VIM slowed down so I suspected "undo levels" to be pretty large. I'm using an `undofile` and files have grown pretty large (I think) (Around 300KB each)

I'm wondering if there's a way to truncate those files without hurting the most recent history.

Comment: Personally I find it is mostly plugins and long lines cause slow downs in Vim. Have you installed any plugins recently? Is the slow down only happen on certain files?

Comment: I haven't installed new plugins.. The slowdown is happening on some of my large Ruby files. I noticed that if the whole line is showing horizontally, there's less lag than when part of the line is showing. When I split vertically, things slow down especially when typing. Having syntax highlight off speeds up my vim obviously. I'll inspecting my plugins etc.. but I'm intrigued how to truncate the undo files :-)

Comment: Do you have syntax fold enabled?

Answer (score 0):

The undo file is appended to at the bottom of the file. The only way to truncate the file without affecting your most recent history is to remove entries from the top of the file.

Comment: It looks like a binary file or are you saying the undo history is line by line and removing the top 10 lines for example would remove the oldest 10 "undos"?

Comment: Since it's a binary file, you would have to pre-process it. I'm not suggesting that you simply open a text editor and delete the lines, however, if you look at binary mode in vim or xxd, this may give you some pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer =) Unfortunately, this is what I first did before asking my question. I'm wondering if there's something simpler than that =)